# ASP.Net MVC5:How to encrypt decrypt connection string in web.config

Tags: asp.net, encryption, web-config

Just read this article http://tutorialslink.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-Webconfig/52

they said if we use this command then connection string will be encrypted `aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" "<Path of the Folder containing the Web.Config file>"` and
say this command will decrypt the connection string `aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" "<Path of the Folder containing the Web.Config file>"`

but the problem is if we follow this approach it may not work when we host our web site in different pc.

so please tell me what approach we should follow to **encrypt / decrypt** **connection string or any section  in web.config** which will work in any pc.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place? The connection string is supposed to be hidden from the outside anyway.

Comment: i want to do it even if anyone can hack web.config they will not be able to read db connection details easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how sensitive your data is, but I suppose you could try the following:

1. Encrypt the connectionString manually first (for instance, with [AES(Rijndael)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx)).
2. Paste the encrypted string in your web.config.
3. Decrypt the string in your code, using something like this

   ```
   private string getConnectionString()
   {
       string encrypted = System.Configuration.
             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];

       //Rijndael or any other form of decryption here...
       //.....
       //.....

       return decryptedString;
   }
   ```
4. Use the decrypted connectionString to connect to your database! :)

Comment: i want to use anything in-built in asp.net which encrypt and decrypt data automatically. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Once you paste the encrypted string, you shouldn't have to worry about it :) Also, AES encryption is built right into the .NET Framework

Comment: the approach what you have explain that is normal encrypt decrypt operation but i am looking for something where asp.net will do it on behalf of developer. anyway thanks for your reply.